# urllib2.HTTPError: While Web Scraping a huge list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The web page has a huge list of journal names with other details. I am trying to scrape the table content into dataframe.

```
#http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2015.html

import bs4 as bs 
import urllib  #Using python 2.7
import pandas as pd 

dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2015.html/', header=0)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('citefactor_list.csv', header=True)
```

But I am getting following error .. I did try referring to some already raised questions but could not fix.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_impact_factor.py", line 7, in <module>
    dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2015.html/', header=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 896, in read_html
    keep_default_na=keep_default_na)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 733, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 727, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 196, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 450, in _build_doc
    return BeautifulSoup(self._setup_build_doc(), features='html5lib',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 443, in _setup_build_doc
    raw_text = _read(self.io)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 130, in _read
    with urlopen(obj) as url:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 60, in urlopen
    with closing(_urlopen(*args, **kwargs)) as f:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 500 internal server error means something went wrong on the server and therefore is out of your control.

However the problem is that you are using the wrong URL.

If you go to http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2015.html/ in your browser you get a 404 not found error. Remove the trailing slash i.e. http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2015.html and it will work.

Comment: Is there any possibility that I can scrape dataframe based on a ISSN number or title search ? without mentioning any url to refer ?